# Не удается развернуть сайт на VDS на Django в Ubuntu

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, vds, gunicorn

Пытаюсь развернуть на VDS сайт на Django. ОС - Ubuntu 22.04

При работе в виртуальном окружении после выполнения команды `gunicorn --bind 11.222.333.44:8000 main_application.wsgi` сайт благополучно открывается по адресу http://11.222.333.44:8000

После деактивации виртуального окружения при попытке открыть сайт по адресу http://mysite.ru возвращается 502 ошибка. В чем может быть проблема, может не удалось Gunicorn c Nginx "поженить"?

Содержимое файла конфигурации gunicorn (/etc/systemd/system/myproject.gunicorn.service):

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=myuser
Group=myuser
WorkingDirectory=/home/myuser/myproject/
ExecStart=/home/myuser/myproject/env/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/myuser/myproject/server.sock main_application.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

При выполнении команды `sudo systemctl status myproject.gunicorn` получаю следующий результат:

```
myproject.gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/myproject.gunicorn.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (running) since Sun 2022-07-31 16:39:45 MSK; 43min ago
Main PID: 45050 (gunicorn)
Tasks: 4 (limit: 1033)
Memory: 95.1M
CPU: 1.124s
```

Содержимое файла конфигурации nginx (/etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject):

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name mysite.ru www.mysite.ru 11.222.333.44;
  location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

  location /static/ {
    root /home/myuser/myproject/;
  }

  location /admin/static/ {
    root /home/myuser/myproject/;
  }

  location / {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/home/myuser/myproject/server.sock;
  }
}
```

Результат работы команды `sudo nginx -t`:

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

Результат работы команды `systemctl status nginx`:

```
nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (running) since Sun 2022-07-31 16:49:47 MSK; 45min ago
Docs: man:nginx(8)
Process: 45351 ExecReload=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; -s reload (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 45205 (nginx)
Tasks: 2 (limit: 1033)
Memory: 2.8M
CPU: 56ms
```

Comment: А у вас приложение на 8000 TCP-порту, а nginx ломится в unix domain socket. Это так и надо?

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev Не знаю. А как надо?